# Add contentInset to a tableView which has tableHeaderView

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uiscrollview

I have a tableView which will have a tableHeaderView and I need to add contentInset to that tableView.

I am facing a situation where contentInset applied from sectionHeader and cells. I am seeing an empty gap between sectionHeader and tableHeaderView.

Requirement is the gap present between tableHeaderView and sectionHeader must be present over the tableHeaderView.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Reason for that is tableHeaderView is added above contentView.

contentInsets will be added to the contentView.